# Backbone.js Performance - Adding a class to first and last model of a nested collection

Tags: javascript, performance, backbone.js, iteration

I have a list of ~100 products that are displayed in a long list on one page. Each product belongs to one category, I have about 5 categories. Every product has a category_id.

I want to add a '.first' class to every first product of a category and a '.last' class to every last product of a category.

Performance is key, I came up with a few solutions myself but the were very poorly written and too cumbersome.

Example data:

```
products = {
   id: 1, category_id: 1;
   id: 2, category_id: 1;
   id: 3, category_id: 1;
   id: 4, category_id: 2;
   id: 5, category_id: 2;
   id: 6, category_id: 2;
   id: 7, category_id: 3;
   id: 8, category_id: 3;
   ...
}
```

Result I'm looking for:

```
<ul>

  <li class='first' id='1'></li>
  <li id='2'></li>
  <li class='last' id='3'></li>

  <li class='first' id='4'></li>
  <li id='5'></li>
  <li class='last' id='6'></li>

  <li class='first' id='7'></li>
  <li id='8'></li>
  ...
</ul>
```

EDIT: Thank you for the help @niemand! I used groupBy and this is what I have so far. Is this a good way to go about this, performance wise?

```
window.firsts = []
window.lasts = []
@grouped = _.groupBy(@collection.toJSON(), 'category_id')
_.each @grouped, (group) ->
  window.firsts.push new App.Models.Piece(_.first(group)).get('id')
  window.lasts.push new App.Models.Piece(_.last(group)).get('id')
```

This way I can check if window.firsts or window.lasts contains the current model's id when I am rendering out each model view and apply the correct class. If there is a more performant way of going about this I'd love to know!

Comment: Why don't you show us what you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Backbone.Collection.where({category_id: <category_id>})` to create a 2-dimensional array, which contains models grouped by categories. You will be able to find needed data easily then.

Or, if you don't mind about the order of models inside the categories, then just `Backbone.Collection.sortBy()`, iterate through the collection and find all the indexes, where category_id gets changed at.

The first way is better if you have a list of category_id's and it's small. The second is better for a large volume of data.

**Edit:**

There is an Underscore function groupBy() for collections! So you should use it: `collection.groupBy(function(model) {return model.get('category_id');});`